# multiply vector by variable to create a matrix with for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a matrix that will demonstrate a industry production projected in the next x years.

First I have created a for loop to create the columns names with: (10 years for example)

```
column.name <- vector()
for (i in 1:10) {
    object <- paste('ano.',i)
    column.name[i] <- object
}
```

then I saved my products in a vector

```
products <- c('a','b','c',)
```

In this case I have a machine that will be used for all three products. So, I have a participacion vector, indicating how much of each product will be produced considering the machine capacity (4800).

```
participation<- c(0.60,0.20,0.20)
amount <- 4800
```

finaly i tried to multiplicate 'participation' by amout with a for loop

```
prod <- matrix(length(products):length(column.name))
for (j in 1:length(column.name)) {
  for (i in 1:length(product)) {
    dado <- participation[i]*amount
    prod[i,j] <- dado
  }
  return(prod)
}
```

theoretically I would get a matrix with production values for each year by product, which would be used to calculate the income. However, all I got was a 1x1 matrix with null value.

Could you help me?

Comment: Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: ano.1 ano.2 ano.3 ano.4 ano.5 ano.6 ano.7 ano.8 ano.9 ano.10
[1,]       a  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880   2880
[2,]       b   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960    960
[3,]       c   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960    960

Answer (score 0):

You were close, here is a working version of your example:

```
column.name <- vector()
for (i in 1:10) {
  object <- paste('ano.',i)
  column.name[i] <- object
}

products <- c('a','b','c')

participation<- c(0.60,0.20,0.20)
amount <- 4800

prod <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = length(products), ncol = length(column.name))

for (j in 1:length(column.name)) {
  for (i in 1:length(products)) {
    dado <- participation[i]*amount
    prod[i,j] <- dado
  }
}
```

A few things to consider:

- `matrix()` creates a new matrix with parameters: data, nrow, ncol (in that order). You should either specify each parameter in order or explicitly name parameters (ie. `nrow=`) otherwise your first parameter gets interpreted as the `data` parameter.
- Careful around typos! You had `length(product)` rather than `length(products)`, you had an extra comma in `products`, etc.
- A deeper question, outside the scope of your specific ask, is whether you should be using matrices versus data.frames for your analysis.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but now I got a 3x10 matrix but only the first column has the values. All others are NA.

Comment: Are you clearing your environment (of any old R objects) and running this sample code in isolation? You should be getting a 3x10 matrix that looks like this `> prod
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] 2880 2880 2880 2880 2880 2880 2880 2880 2880  2880
[2,]  960  960  960  960  960  960  960  960  960   960
[3,]  960  960  960  960  960  960  960  960  960   960`

Comment: Let me know if your desired output is something else.

Comment: yes, this is the desired output and I am running al my code. I put 'rm(list = ls(all=T))' to clean everything before my code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
column.name <- paste0('ano.', 1:10)
products <- c('a','b','c')
participation<- c(0.60,0.20,0.20)
amount <- 4800

mat <- matrix(NA, 
              nrow = 3, 
              ncol = 10,
              dimnames = list(product = products,
                              ano = column.name))


mat[] <- participation * amount

mat
#>        ano
#> product ano.1 ano.2 ano.3 ano.4 ano.5 ano.6 ano.7 ano.8 ano.9 ano.10
#>       a  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880   2880
#>       b   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960    960
#>       c   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960    960
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Another option is to use the `outer` function, and name the rows and columns of the matrix after it is produced

```r
participation<- c(0.60,0.20,0.20)
amount <- rep(4800, 10)

mat <- outer(participation, amount)

colnames(mat) <- paste0('ano.', 1:10)
row.names(mat) <- c('a','b','c')

mat
#>   ano.1 ano.2 ano.3 ano.4 ano.5 ano.6 ano.7 ano.8 ano.9 ano.10
#> a  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880  2880   2880
#> b   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960    960
#> c   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960   960    960
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>